# Twitter and FaceBook integration in BB 10

Tags: facebook, twitter, integration, blackberry-10

I have read that there are Twitter api like (Twitter API ME)which helps to access the main functionalities of twitter directly from our app.Is this possible? Did twitter provides such API? What is the case of Facebook integration? Anyone please help me by providing related links or sample app for the same in BB 10 
   Iam using cascades SDK, QNX MOMENTICS is the IDE

Answer (score 2):

There is a twitter API available for Blackberry 10 . I have used it and it work successfully.
You can download it from Github and i am providing the link for you. [Twitter API for BB10](https://github.com/kylefowler/twitter-bb10)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not provide Qt API to access their main functionalities. However there is a Qt API that supports most of Twitter APIs it can be found here https://github.com/minimoog/QTweetLib. 
There is also Facebook graph api port to Qt - http://gitorious.net/qfacebook. Both APIs rely on QtCore and QtNetwork so they should be portable to BB 10.